# Visual Studio 2013 Setup Project - IpOverUsbSvc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

Let's assume

> - I've a C# application (Visual Studio 2013)
> - and a setup project (Visual Studio Installer Projects) for it.

When I try to install the generated msi-file I get the following error message:

> The following applications are using files which the installer must update. You can either close the application and click "Try Again", or click "Continue" so that the installer continues the installation, and replaces these files when your system restarts.
>
> Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) (Process Id: xxxx)

How can I get rid of this error message?

I know that I can terminate this windows service which comes with Visual Studio. But I don't wont to do that on all clients which have Visual Studio installed.

I'm not using Windows Phone in my application. Why does the installer tries to replace that file?

Regards Wollmich

Comment: Be sure to click No!  Given that you don't want to document what you deploy, it will be a lot easier to just get rid of that installer and ask a team member to create one.

Comment: When I change the `REINSTALLMODE` property from `amus` to `dmus` then I don't see the error message anymore.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of stating the obvious, it means that you are installing a file that the phone service also uses.  Remember that there are many common files shared by Windows apps, such as C++ run times and others.  Unless you list the files you are installing then nobody can know which file it is. Be careful that you are not installing Windows shared files in your MSI instead of with a standard redistributable that should be installed via prerequisites.

If you do the install and create a log file with msiecec /I [path to your msi] /l*v [path to text log file] you can then look in the log file. There should be 1603 messages that say exactly which files are the issue.

The big issue with REINSTALLMODE and damus is that it applies to ALL files in the MSI that are being installed, so it won't update any of your older files either. The right thing to do is figure out what files are involved and why you are sharing them with a phone service.

Note that it is strictly speaking not an error message - it's a standard files-in-use dialog telling you that you can avoid a potential reboot by shutting down the process(es) using files that need updating.